Foreign Film of two young brothers
I need help with this movie, it is in a European language, maybe Greek, Spanish, Portuguese, French, etc.  Definitely not in English or a language from an Asian country.
It is a coming of age movie surrounding two brothers who go on a day trip with their father, with whom they didn't have a close relationship with.  The movie starts at the mother's house, with the brothers eventually leaving with the father on their trip.  At some point in the movie the car they were traveling in gets stuck in the mud and the father teaches them how to get it out using a wooden plank.
Later on they end up in a deserted/forested area and the father climbs up a tower (unsure as to why).  The father ends up falling from the tower, dying when he hits the ground.  Both of the siblings witness his death.  Later on the brothers end up using the plank trick to get their vehicle unstuck from mud again.
The colour-scheme was dark and bleak.  My lecturer also mentioned that there were many still shots in the film that referenced famous paintings.

Do you remember the year\decade?

"Foreign" depends where you live. Everywhere is foreign to someone.

It's a Russian movie, correct?  (There is a scene where they are eating dinner and the father tears the roast chicken apart with his hands?)  I saw it at a festival years ago but I can't remember the title!

@DukeZhou i cannot remember the dinner scene but i know in the front part of the film, the children were at their mothers home and the story lingers for awhile before they set off for the road trip.

@DukeZhou Thank you for the Russian tip!

(@Liona the chicken scene made a big impression on me as a Westerner, b/c although I understand using the hands is both manly and traditional, it's unheard of in the US. :)

I believe it is the Russian film The Return directed by Andrey Zvyagintsev.
From the plot synopsis:

Ivan has an outburst of anger after witnessing his father strike Andrei. He shouts at his father, runs into the forest, and climbs to the top of the observatory tower. Andrei and their father run after him. The father tries to talk with Ivan, but this only stresses Ivan further. He then threatens to jump down from the top of the tower. The father tries to reach out to him, but falls and dies.


Yes, it is. Thank you so much!

@LiOng  No problem.  I was just thinking of the film the other day, and thought it would be nice to have a question about it.  PS: don't forget to up-vote!

This is my first time using this website and it is ridiculously fast and efficient, love it! This film was used in my art philosophy class a few years ago, had a tough week trying to figure this out. I have upvoted the comment too :)

@LiOng you should accept the answer to appreciate the answer by clicking the tick mark
